# IndexOutOfBoundsException when calling recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am fairly new to Java and trying to write an algorithm that returns that sum of the indices of pairs that equal a total.

I am getting an error when I hit my recursive function about the bounds. The bounds seem fine to me, I am just passing in the updated arraylist so I don't know where its coming from.

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
  at com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld.getMatches(HelloWorld.java:36)
  at com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld.getMatches(HelloWorld.java:41)
```

Algorithm

```
public class HelloWorld {

ArrayList<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> param = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1));

    int res = new HelloWorld().pairwise(param, 1);
    System.out.println(res);
}

private int pairwise(ArrayList<Integer> arr, Integer total) {
    for (Integer item: arr) {
        this.temp.add(item);
    }
    getMatches(this.temp, total);
    return getIndices(this.matches, arr);
}

private void getMatches(ArrayList<Integer> arr, Integer total) {
    boolean noMatch = true;

    for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        if (arr.get(0) + arr.get(i) == total) {
            //add to matches
            this.matches.add(arr.get(0));
            this.matches.add(arr.get(i));

            //remove from temp
            this.temp.remove(0);
            this.temp.remove(arr.get(i));

            noMatch = false;
            if (this.temp.size() > 1) {
                //ERROR HERE
                getMatches(this.temp, total);
            }

        }
    }
    if (noMatch) {
        this.temp.remove(0); //remove first one
        if (this.temp.size() > 1) {
            getMatches(this.temp, total);
        }
    }
}

private int getIndices(ArrayList<Integer> matches, ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer item: matches) {
        int index = array.indexOf(item);
        count += index;
        array.set(index, -3000);
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

urm... you're removing elements from the array you're iterating over...

here:

```
for (int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++) {
  //...code
}
```

You're looping through the initial size of the array which is 6. Then *inside* of the for loop body you're **removing** elements from the array you're looping through:

```
//remove from temp
this.temp.remove(0);
this.temp.remove(arr.get(i));
```

Every iteration makes the array shorter which is why you're getting Out of bound exceptions.

You'll want to duplicate the array you pass to `getMatches` i.e.

```
getMatches(new ArrayList<>(this.temp), total);
```

This way you'll be removing elements from `temp` but won't be affecting the array you're actually iterating over: `arr`

Comment: Thats it! I even realized this before and was looking at `list iterators` in a different approach. Thanks, time for a break...

Answer (score 1):

You must remove element at `i` then remove `0`:

```
        //remove from temp
        this.temp.remove(arr.get(i));
        this.temp.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -1 in the for condition

```
private void getMatches(ArrayList<Integer> arr, Integer total) {
boolean noMatch = true;

for (int i=1; i<arr.size()-1; i++) {
    if (arr.get(0) + arr.get(i) == total) {
        //add to matches
        this.matches.add(arr.get(0));
        this.matches.add(arr.get(i));

        //remove from temp
        this.temp.remove(0);
        this.temp.remove(arr.get(i));

        noMatch = false;
        if (this.temp.size() > 1) {
            //ERROR HERE
            getMatches(this.temp, total);
        }

    }
}
if (noMatch) {
    this.temp.remove(0); //remove first one
    if (this.temp.size() > 1) {
        getMatches(this.temp, total);
    }
}
```

}